# CSV data : how to tabulate and manage

Tags: python, csv

Goodmorning guys,
I have a list of strings badly formatted, see the following example:

```
Gi1/0/1, Gi1/0/2, Gi1/0/3, Gi1/0/4, Gi1/0/5, Gi1/0/6, Gi1/0/7, Gi1/0/8, Gi1/0/9, Gi1/0/10, Gi1/0/11, Gi1/0/12, 

                                          Gi1/0/13, Gi1/0/15, Gi1/0/16, Gi1/0/17, Gi1/0/18, Gi1/0/19, Gi1/0/20, Gi1/0/21, Gi1/0/22, Gi1/0/23, Gi1/0/24
```

I need to get a new list with 8 strings per row, a beginning message and a string between each row, like the following:

```
int range Gi1/0/1, Gi1/0/2, Gi1/0/3, Gi1/0/4, Gi1/0/5, Gi1/0/6, Gi1/0/7, Gi1/0/8 
authentication open
int range Gi1/0/9, Gi1/0/10, Gi1/0/11, Gi1/0/12, Gi1/0/13, Gi1/0/15, Gi1/0/16, Gi1/0/17
authentication open
```

... and so on ...

I'm trying by using csv.reader and writer but I have no idea how to manage these data and get the output I need. Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
initial_data = """Gi1/0/1, Gi1/0/2, Gi1/0/3, Gi1/0/4, Gi1/0/5, Gi1/0/6, Gi1/0/7, Gi1/0/8, Gi1/0/9, Gi1/0/10, Gi1/0/11, Gi1/0/12,

Gi1/0/13, Gi1/0/15, Gi1/0/16, Gi1/0/17, Gi1/0/18, Gi1/0/19, Gi1/0/20, Gi1/0/21, Gi1/0/22, Gi1/0/23, Gi1/0/24"""

# Splitting and removing whitespaces 
# i.e. converting Gi1/0/1, Gi1/0/2 to ["Gi1/0/1", "Gi1/0/2"]
data = [i.strip() for i in initial_data.split(",")]

# functions to break the list 
# into n elements per list
def chunks(data, n):
    chunk = []
    for i in range(0, len(data), n):
        chunk.append(data[i:i + n])
    return chunk

chunked_data = chunks(data, 8)

output_list = []
for i in chunked_data:
    # adding "int range" and "authentication open"
    output_list.append("int range " + ", ".join(j for j in i) + " authentication open")
```

The value of `output_list` will be

```
['int range Gi1/0/1, Gi1/0/2, Gi1/0/3, Gi1/0/4, Gi1/0/5, Gi1/0/6, Gi1/0/7, Gi1/0/8 authentication open',
 'int range Gi1/0/9, Gi1/0/10, Gi1/0/11, Gi1/0/12, Gi1/0/13, Gi1/0/15, Gi1/0/16, Gi1/0/17 authentication open',
 'int range Gi1/0/18, Gi1/0/19, Gi1/0/20, Gi1/0/21, Gi1/0/22, Gi1/0/23, Gi1/0/24 authentication open']
```

Comment: Many many thanks!! 
I've managed the code by using your suggestions and it works very well . 
I removed the quotes and added a line before the last message I need. 

Thanks again